# Can We Change the Capacitance of a Capacitor

Tags: charge, capacitance, voltage, geometry, dielectric

Can we change the capacitor capacity by changing existing charge
 On the plates when it is connected to the battery?

Comment: Seems like I remember that there is some sort of solid-state capacitor in which the capacitance can be changed by changing the voltage on it (or, equivalently, changing the charge on it). It has the structure of a reversed-biased PN junction and relies on the fact that the depletion layer thickness changes (which is effectively the distance between the "plates" of the capacitor) as the voltage across the reversed-bias PN junction changes. Don't recall offhand what the device is called, however.

Comment: @SamuelWeir, [varicaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap) have been used for years in, e.g, UHF TV tuners but I'm not sure that's what the OP is asking (to be sure, it's not clear to me what's being asked).  It seems to me that the OP is stipulating that the voltage across the capacitor is fixed by the battery and, somehow, the charge on the plates is changed while connected to the battery.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri: Yep it seems to me what is being asked for is some sort of "nonlinear capacitor" that doesn't obey $C = \frac{Q}{V}$ just as there are non-ohmic resistors that don't obey $V = IR$ for constant $R$.

Comment: I would say to him that if he's just thinking of an ordinary parallel plate capacitor then the answer is no ... UNLESS you put so much voltage on it you create a force that warps the capacitor plates! Ahhh ... there you go, the sweet smell of real life defying simple models, just as if you stick too much power through a resistor it damages it and changes the resistance.

Comment: FWIW that means the system over long scales not only displays nonlinearity but _hysteresis_ , the dependence of its current state on its past history...

Comment: @mike4ty4, perhaps but I'm not so sure.  I think the OP is thinking that, for an ordinary, e.g., parallel plate vacuum capacitor, if $V$ is held constant by, e.g., a battery, then C must change if Q is changed.  But instead, it must be realized that if Q (V) is changed, *V (Q) must change* since C is a (ideally) independent of Q and V.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri: That's why I suggested non ideal behavior of the capacitor. That he mentions "plates" though suggests he thinks a parallel plate capacitor, in which case no, you cannot change the capacitance just with voltage because the charge will always be in suitable proportion. Unless as I said you put on so much voltage you damage the capacitor.

Comment: EDIT: Now I see, he's asking about CHARGE, if adding CHARGE can change the capacitance... So I suspect he's imagining it connected to the battery then using some EXTERNAL source to add additional charge against the capacitor plates...

Comment: All backbiased pn junctions act as a variable capacitor controlled by the bias voltage, see varactor diodes. When a small voltage, "signal", is injected over the bias voltage a "differential" dynamic capacitance can be utilized. This is a very common element in almost all voltage controlled oscillators and passive filters. It can also be used as a parametric amplifier and/or mixer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed voltage dependent capacitors where the capacitance is a function of applied voltage, that is, $C(v)$ where $v$ is applied voltage.  Although there may be newer technology these days, there used to be dielectric materials used in capacitors made of ferroelectric materials where the applied voltage polarizes the dipoles in the dielectric thus changing the field strength and thus the capacitance.  Usually these are non-linear capacitance changes.  More information should be easily located via Google search on voltage dependent capacitors.

The OP question though is not as precise as needed to determine if this is valid information as an answer.  In particular, "while connected to a battery" may imply fixed voltage source.  Changing charge on existing plates is in fact what happens in capacitors during charging and discharging cycles.  With a fully charged capacitor with applied DC voltage, no more current will flow.  This means the charge accumulated in the capacitor is now fixed.  To change that you change one of the following:  (1) voltage, (2) capacitance via changing physical dimensions or insertion of different dielectric material or varying the dielectric material in the capacitor.

Comment: Indeed, some dielectrics yield notoriously [voltage dependent capacitance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQfFL.png).

Answer (score -1):

Using the formula q=CV where V is constant you can change capacitance by changing charge on plate , you can also intrinsically change its value by inserting di electric slab combinations between the plates.